# Script button click behaving not like user click

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

In my android app, I have a Play button. After I manually clicked the button, everything works fine. but when I use uiautomator to trigger the button click, nothing happend. After debugging, I am pretty sure it is the string comparison step (labeled stuck here) that causes the failure. Very confused why it behaves differently. I do see the button get clicked in both ways (with button color change). If I use button.getText().toString(), both worked. BTW, button.getText() returns CharSequence, not String object.

I defined my string values in res/values/strings.xml as

```
<string name="play">Play</string>
```

The java code:

```
private final static String PLAY = "Play";        

//some code in between    

Button playButton = new Button(this);
playButton.setText(R.string.play);
playButton.setTextSize(BUTTON_FONT_SIZE);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Button b = (Button) v;
       if (b.getText().equals(PLAY)) {    //stuck here.                                    
             startPlay();
        } else {

            stopPlay();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please share how you tried to click the button using UiAutomator. Below code should work
UiObject buttonToClick = new UiObject(new UiSelector ().text(Play).className("android.widget.Button"));     buttonToClick.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

Comment: I use the script to drive the commands in UIAutomator. Everything is automatic. The problem is manual click has no problem. They use the same code, but behave differently.